# how to calculate the collapsable div height to get the menu bar fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Refer this page first](http://jmkumaresh.com/aaron/)

You may seen a link at the top the page says collapse this section. So when user click the link the section below is gets open and close.

And there is a fixed menu bar, when the browsers top section reaches the collapsible section end, the menu bar gets fixed. And the item inside that section collapsible div may gets vary.

Now what I want is how to  calculate the height of that div by

1. while it is opened
2. while it is closed
3. while there is more list elements than it is shown and get the menu bar fixed according the height.

Thanks

Comment: Your link doesn't work (404). Can you post the related code here as well?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you linked us to page on your local network.

Anyway, pretty easy to do with jQuery. We'll call the fixed div .fixed:

```
var fixed = $('.fixed');
var openHeight = 0; var closedHeight = 0;
fixed.on('click', function() {
  if(fixed.hasClass('collapsed') {
    //code to expand div
    fixed.removeClass('collapsed');
    openHeight = fixed.height();
   }
  else {
    //code to collapse div
    fixed.addClass('collapsed');
    closedHeight = fixed.height();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what the third part of your question is asking, you might want to clarify that